# Perl: Print variables not found in "unless -e" statement

Tags: perl

I have this line of code:

```
unless((-e $FileOne) && (-e $Filetwo) && (-e $FileThree)) {die "$!\n";}
```

where, the $ variables contain file names with full paths.

This statement checks if all the 3 files are present, else, it will `die`.

Is there any Perl 'Special Variable' that I could use in the `die` statement that would let me know which out of the three files are missing (i.e., which out of the three `-e` checks have failed) ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to alias the variables to $_:

```
-e or die "$_: $!\n" for $FileOne, $Filetwo, $FileThree;
```

Note that if Filetwo is missing, the existence of FileThree is not even tested (as in the original code).

Comment: this thing works.. thanks! just a query - is this just another way of writing:
`for ($VBRegCopy, $VBUnregCopy, $ISMTemplate) {-e $_ or die "$_: $!\n"};`

Answer (score 2):

This will show you all files that are missing, NOT only first one missing,

```
@$_ and die "Files missing: @$_\n" 
  for [ grep { !-e } $FileOne, $Filetwo, $FileThree ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. You test the compound condition, and then die based on evaluation.

Longer answer: Depends how attached you are to it being a 'one liner'.

Rewriting as:

```
foreach my $file ( @file_list ) {
   die "$file does not exist\n" unless -e $file;
}
```

should have the same result. You can transform:

```
NOT ( A AND B AND C )
```

into:

```
NOT A 
OR NOT B
OR NOT C
```

(Which the latter  case effectively is) 
using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score -1):

perhaps a '-e' missing ?

```
unless((-e $FileOne) && (-e $Filetwo) && (-e $FileThree)) {die "$!\n";}
```

with the three '-e' :)

use negation carrefully

!(A & B & C) = !A | !B | !C

so use 'if' instead of 'unless'

```
if ((-e $FileOne) && (-e $Filetwo) && (-e $FileThree)) {die "$!\n";}
```

or

```
unless((!-e $FileOne) || (!-e $Filetwo) || (!-e $FileThree)) {die "$!\n";}
```